# os.path.isdir check failing

Tags: python, unix

I have the following code where I am trying to check for directory "Gerrits/HEAD/wlan" and then do some operations,for some reason if condition to check for the directory keeps failing even thought the directory exists?
anything wrong with the if condition@if (os.path.isdir(SCRIPT_ROOT + "/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")): below

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call

SCRIPT_ROOT=subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print SCRIPT_ROOT

def main ():
    if (os.path.isdir(SCRIPT_ROOT + "/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")):
        print "SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan already exists,cloning it again to the tip"
        check_call("rm -rf $SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan ", shell=True)
        check_call("cd Gerrits/HEAD",shell=True)
    else:
        print "SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan doesn't exist,cloning it"
        os.makedirs("Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")
        check_call("cd Gerrits/HEAD",shell=True)
        currdir=subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:-

```
SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan doesn't exist,cloning it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 16, in main
    os.makedirs("Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'Gerrits/HEAD/wlan'
```

Comment: Please narrow the question down before asking. That is way too much stuff to wade through.

Comment: @JeremyVisser - thats exactly what I did ,please readthrough again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.strip()` to your `communicate()[0]` calls, the code as is includes trailing newline in the output.

Just to be sure, your script that I just tested on a linux box with Python 2.5.

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call

SCRIPT_ROOT=subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
print SCRIPT_ROOT

def main ():
    if (os.path.isdir(SCRIPT_ROOT + "/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")):
        print "SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan already exists,cloning it again to the tip"
        check_call("rm -rf %s/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan" % SCRIPT_ROOT, shell=True)
        check_call("cd Gerrits/HEAD",shell=True)
    else:
        print "SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan doesn't exist,cloning it"
        os.makedirs("Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")
        check_call("cd Gerrits/HEAD",shell=True)
        currdir=subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And its output:

```
vlazarenko@xx:~$ python o.py 
/media/home/vlazarenko
SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan already exists,cloning it again to the tip
```

Comment: even after adding .strip() it still thinks it doesnt exist

Comment: Pasted complete script with changes that does work in my environment, granted I reproduced the existence of `Gerrits/HEAD/wlan` in my homedir.

Comment: I switched to os.getcwd() but now the remove is failing @"check_call("rm -rf $SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan ", shell=True)" is failing... how to change this rm statement to remove whole "Gerrits/HEAD/wlan" if it exists...

Comment: `$SCRIPT_ROOT` won't evaluate, it's not shell :) You need to either `+` it as you did in other parts of your code or use other string formatting methods.

Comment: thanks,did "check_call("cd Gerrits/HEAD",shell=True)" work for you?

Comment: we can easily switch to os.chdir but just curious why  "check_call("cd Gerrits/HEAD",shell=True)" is not working?

Comment: If you are expecting your current shell to move there, it won't work. The reason to that is that you're saying `shell=True`, which means that the call will be done in a separate sub-shell. Hence, it spawns a shell, `cd`s there and closes the shell. Your current environment remains unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

When I execute this line of code here:

```
SCRIPT_ROOT=subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

...the value of `SCRIPT_ROOT` has a trailing newline

```
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> ROOT = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> ROOT
'/Users/bgporter/personal\n'
```

...which makes this call

```
if (os.path.isdir(SCRIPT_ROOT + "/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan")):
```

behave differently than you'd like it to. You can either call strip() on that value, or if you always want to get the current working directory, you can do that much more easily by calling [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Similarly, you can use the [`os.removedirs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.removedirs) function to recursively remove the directories you don't want instead of shelling out.

Comment: I changed to os.getcwd but somehow the script still thinks that the directory doesnt exist

Comment: I think now "check_call("rm -rf $SCRIPT_ROOT/Gerrits/HEAD/wlan ", shell=True)" is failing... how to change this rm statement to remove whole "Gerrits/HEAD/wlan" if it exists...